# How to connect react-hook-form with useState and react-select?

Tags: reactjs, react-select, react-hook-form

I am using *yup version ^0.32.11* *react-select version ^5.3.2* and     *react-hook-form version ^7.32.1*

I want to created validated form by Yup and react-hook-form which use react-select to present date as a select dropdown.

My problem is that I catch an error `` border must be a `object` type, but the final value was: `null` (cast from the value `"strawberry"`). If "null" is intended as an empty value be sure to mark the schema as `.nullable()` ``

I read all documentation but cannot find a solution. My code looks like:

```
      const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({

      border: Yup.object().shape({
                value: Yup.string().required('Województwo jest obowiązkowe'),
                label: Yup.string().required('Województwo jest obowiązkowe'),

              }),
              });

{* not important code *}

return (

// not important code

 <Controller
                   control={control}
                   render={({ field: { onChanges, value, name, ref } }) => {
                    const currentSelection = options.find(
                        (c) => c.value === value
                      );
                    const handleSelectChange = (selectedOption) => {
                        setBorder(selectedOption?.value);
                      };
                 return (
                     <Select
                     isClearable
                      inputRef={ref}
                      value={currentSelection}
                      name={border}
                      options={options}
                      onChange={handleSelectChange}
                     />
                   )}}
                   name={"border"}
                />
// not important code

)


I want to use useState because I know how this hook work. In documentation I read that I can connect read-hook-form with all libraries etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your yup schema should look like this

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  border: Yup.string().required('Województwo jest obowiązkowe')
});
```

Also since you are using react hook form you can simplify your select

```
<Controller
  control={control}
  render={({ field: { onChange, value, ref }}) => (
    <Select
      isClearable
      inputRef={ref}
      value={value}
      name="border"
      options={options}
      onChange={onChange}
     />
   )}}
   name="border"
 />
```